# C++ 2-bit bitfield arrays possible?

Tags: c++, bit-fields

I have a struct of 2-bit bitfields like this:

```
struct MyStruct {
    unsigned __int32 info0  : 2;
    unsigned __int32 info1  : 2;
    unsigned __int32 info2  : 2;
   ...
    unsigned __int32 info59 : 2;
};
```

And another like this going up to 120... Is there a way to write and address them as an array?

Comment: Maybe you could wrap something around `std::bitset<240>` ?

Comment: A regular array is accessed by forming a pointer to each element, and you can't have a pointer to a bitfield.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't use Paul R's answer for whatever reason, you can always use a custom accessor with a standard array :

```
static unsigned __int8 infos[30]; // 240 bits allocated

unsigned __int8 getInfo( unsigned short id_num )
{
    return (infos[id_num/4] >> ((2*id_num) % 8) ) & 0x3;
}
// setInfo left as an exercise.
```

(You may need to check the logic here, I haven't tested it.)

Comment: You should replace that `4` with a `sizeof`, otherwise nice answer !

Comment: @Quentin : well, OP is using __intxx, which are bit-length defined types so sizeof is not really useful here. Otherwise I agree.

Comment: @Quentin `sizeof` what exactly? As I understand, the 4 here is `bits_in_byte / bitfield_element_width`.

Comment: Hmm, indeed. `int` confused me and I thought for a moment that we were indexing in an array of (wide) ints, of usual size 4. Since that 4 is actually the number of fields in one byte, my comment makes no sense. Edit : but wait... aren't you returning a reference to a rvalue right here ?

Comment: Am I wrong, or is this code returning a reference to a temporary?

Comment: Also, I think that the shift should be multiplied by the bitfield element width 2. Otherwise you never access the top half of the array element.

Comment: @user2079303: It was pretty flawed. 8 * 40 wasn't 240 either.

Comment: @MSalters : as I said, I've haven't really checked the answer. Moreover the way the 2-bit infos are stacked is not really handy : 3 2 1 0 7 6 5 4 etc.

Answer (score 3):

I would use a proxy object to create a temporary reference which could be used to manipulate 2-bit items using array syntax. This could easily be modified to handle n-bit items.

```
#include <iostream>

class TwoBitArray {
public:
    typedef unsigned char byte;

    TwoBitArray(unsigned size) : bits(new byte[(size + 3) / 4]) {}
    ~TwoBitArray() { delete bits; }

    class tbproxy {
    public:
        tbproxy(byte& b, int pos) : b(b), pos(pos) {}

        // getter
        operator int() const {
            return (b >> (pos * 2)) & 3;
        }

        // setter
        tbproxy operator=(int value) {
            const byte mask = ~(3 << (pos * 2));
            b = (b & mask) | (value << (pos * 2));
            return *this;
        }

    private:
        byte& b;
        int pos;
    };

    // create proxy to manipulate object at index
    tbproxy operator[](int index) const {
        return tbproxy(bits[index/4], index & 3);
    }

private:
    byte* bits;
};

int main() {
    const int size = 20;
    TwoBitArray a(size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        a[i] = i & 3;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        std::cout << i << ": " << a[i] << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I like the answer and certainly appreciate the time you took writing it! For my case, it's kinda overkill, so I'll go with the other answer. It would be interesting to learn, however, why you would choose to use a proxy class over a simple accessor method?

Comment: @Robin - If an object logically forms an array, I would prefer to access it using array syntax. For me, providing the user of a class with a clean, simple and obvious interface far outweighs any implementation complexity concerns. Even if (especially if :) that user is me.