# Store 3 bit binary numbers in C++ array

Tags: c++, binary

I have a program that takes 2 inputs, N and myarray[ ].

```
    cin >> N; 
    cin >> myarray[];
```

In this example say, N=3 which means an integer array of size 3 has to be allocated and suppose that the entries of myarray[ ] are {1,2,3}.

Now I have a function **createsubset()** that creates all the possible subsets of the entries {1,2,3}. The logic that I am following is:

Total number of subsets of a set containing n elements is m=2^n, because an element can be either present or absent in a subset.

So, when m=7 and corresponding binary notation is 111.
Now iterate from m=0 to m=7 to generate all the subsets(except for the set itself which is outcome of m=8):
Example:

```
     m=0, binary=000, subset={ }
     m=1, binary=001, subset={c}
     m=2, binary=010, subset={b}
     m=3, binary=011, subset={b,c}
```

and so on.

This is done by a function **generate()** that iterates from m=0 to m=8.

```
      void generate()
      {
        for(m=0; m<8; m++)
        {
           decimaltobinary(m);

        }
      }
```

Now, I have to store the output of **decimaltobinary()** function (which is a 3-bit binary number) in an array which I will use later to create subsets. This is the part where I am stuck right now.
Can we store a multibit binary number in an array and use it directly?
Please help me regarding this.
Any suggestion regarding the **createsubset()** fuction is also welcomed.

Comment: If you're trying to pack multiple 3-bit numbers into as few ints as possible, take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25381981/c-2-bit-bitfield-arrays-possible/25384425#25384425

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numbers in C/C++ are stored in binary so there is no need to "convert" them.   You can use any C/C++ unsigned integral type you want to to store a 3 bit number so, for example, storing them in std::vector<unsigned char> would work fine.

Along this line, rather than storing the numbers you read into an array [fixed size container] consider storing them in a vector [variable size container] because you don't know the size "up front"