# Is it possible to create a container, whose objects occupy only 2 bits?

Tags: c++, oop, bitset

I'm writing same container with bitset, but for ternary logic, and i have to make it so that one trit( ternary analogue of bit) held only two bits. And i dont know how i can do this, can you give me some ideas?

Comment: The question is completely unclear. If I understood you correctly, the first answer is what you looking for. Keep in mind that AFAIK, `std::bitset` isn't required to occupy only one bit per element.

Answer (score 0):

Struct members in C and C++ may be declared to occupy a given number of bits.
See, for example, [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field).

Answer (score 0):

The right question for Google is "c++ multibit arrays".

The right answer is here -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/25384425/2743554

It seems nothing in libstdc++/boost for managing packaged arrays of N-bits values.